# cocos 2d-x version 3.0 no default proposals in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I am working on cocos2d-x and I have installed cocos2d-x version 3.0 on Windows and after importing project in eclipse (JUNO) i am able to run it but when i try to edit a class member and when i press **CTRL + SPACE** then there is no response i get message that **no default proposals** i have tried setting  path of `cocos2d-x 3.0/cocos/2d` as include path in `C++ general/Settings` and path of `cocos2d-x 3.0/cocos/` as source location in `C++ general/Settings`

Eclipse version -Juno,cocos2d-x version -3.0,and working on windows 7 please help Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

They have a document that describes how to setup Eclipse for Android development: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Build_an_Android_Project_with_Eclipse

Comment: @ Game Developer- i have followed the same instruction for running projects everything is working fine i am able to run the project but when i am trying to edit the classes after importing them help text provided by eclipse is not Displayed